# fatal error: avr\wdt.h: No such file or directory in Arduino Due

Tags: arduino-due

I am using an Arduino Due for vehicle tracking with a GPS/GPRS device. Before using Arduino Due I used an Arduino Uno. When I tryi to load my code in the Arduino Due, it shows me "fatal error: avr\wdt.h: No such file or directory". I can't delete the watchdog from my code as it is important for my device.

Now how can I solve this problem?

Comment: I googled this library https://www.arduinolibraries.info/libraries/sodaq_wdt

Answer (score 1):

The Due is a very different board than the Uno. It uses a completely different architecture (ARM vs AVR). You can't use AVR-specific  code on an ARM chip, and the Watchdog code is AVR-specific.

You will have to find (or write) the equivalent ARM code using the Due's register set instead.

Comment: the question is "Now how can I solve this problem ?"

Comment: This may help: http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=350058.msg2416416